# Socket.io not recognizing connect event

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to learn socket.io and integrate it into an electron app. I am trying to just get the connect event to trigger. It is fairly straightforward and I have ran through the code many times but have not found the issue.

Nothing gets printed to the console when I connect to localhost

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res){
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('test');
});
server.listen(8080);
const socket = require('socket.io')(server);

console.log('server on');
socket.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('user connected');
  console.log(socket);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to this socket on a specific end-point from the client side.

**Server Side**

```
const socketIO = require('socket.io')({path: '/my-first-path'}).listen(server);
socketIO.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', reason => {
        console.log('socket disconnected for ', reason);
    })
})
```

**Client Side**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

let socket = null, serverAddress = 'http://localhost:8080';

socket = io(serverAddress, {
  path: '/my-first-path',
  query: { name: 'Robin', id: '123' }, // optional
  reconnection: true, // optional
  reconnectionDelay: 2000 // optional
});

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('------SOCKET CONNECTION IS ESTABLISHED------');

  socket.on('disconnect', reason => {
    console.log(`------SOCKET CONNECTION IS DISCONNECT, ${reason}-------`);
  });
});

socket.on('reconnect', () => {
  console.log(`------SOCKET CONNECTION IS SUCCESSFULLY RECONNECTED-------`);
});


socket.on('reconnecting', attempt => {
  console.log(`------SOCKET CONNECTION IS ATTEMPTING TO RECONNECT-------`);
});
```

Hope this will helpful. If you want, you can create multiple end-point from server and connect to that end-point from client. On that case, server and client code will be indentical except the path.